# Groupby.median: search delta for each row (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'tin' : [1, 2 , 3, 1, 2, 3],
                   'isin': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b','b','b'], 
                   'price' : [100, 100 , 250, 1000, 1000, 600],
                   })
```

I don't know how as to find a median for every line on condition of group

```
df['median'] = df.groupby(by=['tin','isin']).median() # median by='price'
df['delta'] = df['price']-df['median']

Desirable result:
   tin isin  price delta
0    1    a    100 0
1    2    a    100 0
2    3    a    250 150
3    1    b   1000 0
4    2    b   1000 0
5    3    b    600 400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `mean` for new `Series` with same size like original filled by aggregated values, subtract and if necessary add [`Series.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) for absolute values:

```
 #grouping by isin column only
df['delta'] = df['price'].sub(df.groupby('isin')['price'].transform('median')).abs()
print (df)
   tin isin  price  delta
0    1    a    100      0
1    2    a    100      0
2    3    a    250    150
3    1    b   1000      0
4    2    b   1000      0
5    3    b    600    400
```